# How to limit Google+ OAuth2 with iOS API to one only domain?

Tags: ios, api, dns, google-plus

I'd like to use Google+ OAuth2 in my iOS application and I'm going to use iOS native library provided by Google (API: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/) but the app is to be developed for company internal use and I'd like to restrict G+ OAuth2 to the corporate domain (the company has Google corporate domain already).

So, is there a way to limit a list of google accounts for a user signing-in to the accounts in  corporate domain only, like e.g. mycorpodomain.com?

I couldn't find that possibility in API doc.

Answer (score 1):

The quick solution is to parse the users email address upon return and validate that it uses the whitelisted domain.

Comment: Another option is to parse the id token after sign in. If the account is an apps one, there will be a 'hd' value pointing to the domain, which you can check. The id token is a property on the GPPSignIn object after sign in: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in